# Android, how to receive a signal sent by Process.sendSignal()?

Tags: android, process, signals

There is a Process.sendSignal() method shown in:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#sendSignal(int, int)

My question is: How to receive, detect, catch, handle or whatever it might be called this signal in the destination Process.

Comment: What is your goal? Why would you want to use signals?

Comment: I want running task A to signal running task B to do something from the task ID of running task B.

Comment: I am using Intents. One Intent is task A. The other Intent is task B. I want Intent A to signal Intent B to do something.

Comment: Then post your Intent code for both A & B.

Answer (score 0):

> How to receive, detect, catch, handle or whatever it might be called this signal in the destination Process.

AFAIK, you can't, except perhaps in C/C++. Signals are not meant to be a form of IPC in Android at the SDK level.

> One Intent is task A. The other Intent is task B.

No, they are not. An `Intent` is *data*. It is a *message*. It is not a "task".

> I want Intent A to signal Intent B to do something

That is akin to saying "I want this byte to signal this other byte".

Comment: It seems strange that Android would offer the method, Process.sendSignal(), but would not offer a way for a process the handle that signal.